# TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeydown' of undefined

Tags: javascript, tabs, typeerror, onkeydown

I'm trying to enable the tabulation module in my project. Working module I took from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/support-tabs-in-textareas/ , but when I add this .js to my project i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeydown' of undefined.
```

Its work when i run it on http://jsfiddle.net/zQgTx/ but doesnt work, when I run it in my project. 
Using jquery-1.9.1.
My html code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="." class="navbar-form">
    <textarea id="answer" name="answer" style="width: 700px; height: 250px;"></textarea>
    <br><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Check">
 </form>
```

Help solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: what is the library of Jquery you used?

Comment: Have you got a textarea in your project right? Can you provide the jsfiddle link where it works?

Comment: explains better what you want to do in your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap all your code in `onload` function like this:

```
window.onload = function(){

   // Your code;

}
```

Issue happens because when this line runs :

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
```

your textarea is not actually loaded. `onload` will solve it.